# SED replaces space with new line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a text line that looks like this (there is a space after "poseidon"):

```
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon public/odense_kommune/datastore.xml:17:host">a-postgis1.gues.com</entry>
```

and I use this to delete everything after the first ":"

```
filename=$(sed 's/\:.*$//' <<< $myHost)
```

The result is :

```
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon
public/datastore.xml
```

and it should have been :

```
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon public/datastore.xml
```

it replaces the space with with a new line

I have tried with several SED options but can't figure out what is wrong.

I use the above like this :

```
filename=$(sed 's/\:.*$//' <<< $myHost)
echo Filnavn : $filename >> filn.txt
```

Comment: Hello Julian, you should really format your code: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help I edited your question, it should be available after peer review. Cheers

Comment: Please add how you assign `$myHost`?

Comment: Remember to quote your variable expansions to prevent split+glob

Comment: Are you *sure* that is a space in the first place? Try this: `echo "$myHost" | od -c`

Comment: You might also want to read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` command works for me.

But no need for `sed`, you can use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove everything from the first `:` to the end:

```
filename=${myHost%%:*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cut instead :

```
cut -d ':' -f 1
```

Will select all before the first `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sed` command works for me.

```
$ cat test 
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon public/odense_kommune     /datastore.xml:17:host">a-postgis1.gues.com</entry>
```

SED

```
$ cat test  | sed 's/\:.*//'
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon public/odense_kommune/datastore.xml
```

If you can't use `sed` to solve this problem, you can try `cut` or `awk`.

CUT

```
$ cat test  | cut -d ':' -f1
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon public/odense_kommune/datastore.xml
```

AWK

```
$ cat test  | awk -F ':' '{printf $1}'
/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/poseidon public/odense_kommune/datastore.xml
```